# Get item location in python dictionary by value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary python with keys and values nested.
How do I find the object's index number by providing a value.

As for now, I can get values of the keys in specific object when I know the index of the object.

I mean, if I know the object's index number in the dictionary, I can get the key's and values in this specific object.

```py
my_dict = {
    "ftml": {
        "people": {
            "person": [
                {
                    "@id": "Terach",
                    "@sex": "male",
                    "Death": {
                        "@year": ""
                    },
                    "Midrash": {
                        "@midrah": ""
                    },
                    "Old": {
                        "@age": ""
                    },
                    "Role": {
                        "@role": ""
                    },
                    "birth": {
                        "@year": ""
                    },
                    "father": {
                        "@id": "Nachor"
                    },
                    "mother": {
                        "@id": ""
                    },
                    "spouse": ""
                },
                {
                    "@id": "Avraham",
                    "@sex": "male",
                    "Death": {
                        "@year": "2123"
                    },
                    "Grandson": {
                        "@son1": "Esav",
                        "@son2": "Yaakov"
                    },
                    "Midrash": {
                        "@midrah": ""
                    },
                    "Old": {
                        "@age": "175"
                    },
                    "Role": {
                        "@role": ""
                    },
                    "birth": {
                        "@year": "1948"
                    },
                    "father": {
                        "@id": "Terach"
                    },
                    "mother": {
                        "@id": ""
                    },
                    "spouse": {
                        "@wife1": "Sara"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "@husband": "Avraham",
                    "@id": "Sara",
                    "@sex": "female"
                },
                {
                    "@id": "Nachor",
                    "@sex": "male",
                    "Death": {
                        "@year": ""
                    },
                    "Midrash": {
                        "@midrah": ""
                    },
                    "Old": {
                        "@age": ""
                    },
                    "Role": {
                        "@role": ""
                    },
                    "birth": {
                        "@year": ""
                    },
                    "father": {
                        "@id": "Terach"
                    },
                    "mother": {
                        "@id": ""
                    },
                    "spouse": ""
                },
            ]
        }
    }
}



x = int(input("Type the chronological person number. (i.e 1 is Avraham): "))

print("First Name: ",my_dict['ftml']['people']['person'][x]["@id"]) #1 = avraham
```

I expect to ask the user for the @id and return the object's index number.

For example, if the user sends the program "Avraham" the program will return 1.

If the user is looking for Nachor the program will return 0.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why would `Nachor` return an index of `0`? In the `my_dict['ftml']['people']['person']` list, `Nachor` is in the item with the index of `2`, while `Terach` has index `0`. Also, do you want code that works for just the structure you show or also for a more general structure? Finally, what work have you done on this problem so far and just where are you stuck?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, 
Terach=0, Avraham=1, Sara=2, Nachor=3

Comment: I need to code to work for this structure for now. I have tried several solutions from other questions which did not return any useful result so basically, I did not get any way... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here I used [dict comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) python [Built-in Function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions). It's little bit confusing you. But you know the data structure about [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). For this example I didn't attach your `my_dict` dictionary cause it's too large.

```py
>>> obj = {y["@id"]:x for x,y in list(enumerate(my_dict["ftml"]["people"]["person"]))}
>>> obj
{'Terach': 0, 'Avraham': 1, 'Sara': 2, 'Nachor': 3}
```

This output of the `obj` looks like the summary of the list of `my_dict["ftml"]["people"]["person"]`. Isn't it? For your question this `obj` is simply enough without extracting such a long dictionary and this is fast. If you confusing with [dict comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), hopefully this will understand for you.

```py
>>> obj = {}
>>> for x,y in list(enumerate(my_dict["ftml"]["people"]["person"])):
...     obj[y["@id"]] = x
...
>>> obj
{'Terach': 0, 'Avraham': 1, 'Sara': 2, 'Nachor': 3}
```

If you didn't understand what [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) does in here, check this small example which I directly get it from original documentation.

> Return an enumerate object. iterable must be a sequence, an iterator, or some other object which supports iteration. The `__next__()` method of the iterator returned by `enumerate()` returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over iterable.

```py
>>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
>>> list(enumerate(seasons))
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
>>> list(enumerate(seasons, start=1))
[(1, 'Spring'), (2, 'Summer'), (3, 'Fall'), (4, 'Winter')]
```

According to above the example we are numbering `seasons` final output. I saw you comment in @Joery's answer. Now you want to insert a name and get an index of if it.

```py
>>> x = input("Type the chronological person number. (i.e 1 is Avraham): ")
Type the chronological person id. (i.e 1 is Avraham): Avraham
>>> print(obj.get(x, None))  # if not match anything, will return None
1
```

So this `1` mean the 2nd element of `my_dict["ftml"]["people"]["person"]` list. Now you can easily access any of it. This is what [get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) function does.

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

In you `obj` dictionary there are 4 keys available, `Terach`, `Avraham`, `Sara` and `Nachor`. When you enter one of these as your input, you'll get `0`, `1`, `2` or `3` as an output. According to the default value of [get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) function, it is `None`. When you enter value as an input which is not in `obj` dictionary mean you'll get the default value which is `None`.

Comment: Dear Kushan, your explanation is very educated. I have learned new things from your answer. I will test it later and update with the results. Thank you for sharing the information. It makes coding much easy and fun!

Comment: My pleasure @NoamRotter, waiting for your results. If this helpful for you please select this answer as accepted one by clicking the correct button below the votes of this answer. Thank you too!

Comment: Hi Kushan. 
I have added this code to the script: 
inline `x = input("Type the person name. (i.e Avraham): ")   obj = {}   for x,y in list(enumerate(my_dict["ftml"]["people"]["person"])):   obj[y["@id"]] = x    print(obj)   print(obj.get(x, None))`   
The results are:   
Type the person name. (i.e Avraham): Avraham   
{'Terach': 0, 'Avraham': 1, 'Sara': 2, 'Nachor': 3}   
**None**   
Why did I get None?   
in my code I used the dictionary from the above question.

Comment: This should be work @NoamRotter. As an input, just enter 'Terach'. You'll get '0' as the output. None value return because you entered value not in the obj dictionary. I used it to handle errors when your entered value not in obj dictionary.

Comment: @NoamRotter I just update my answer with more details about get() function and the results you want to get.

Comment: @KushanGunaseketa it seems to be working with python 3.7.4. Will keep checking earlier versions and run some more tests.

Comment: it's working on 3.6 to. I found my mistake. I needed to place this input: `x = input("Type the person name. (i.e Avraham): ")` before `print(obj.get(x, None))` and not at the beginning of the code. Thank you for thorough answer with examples and resources!

Comment: You're welcome and happy hear that @NoamRotter. Let me know if you get anything wrong and sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think revising the dict is a good idea.
Here is my solution:

First get the "position" of your list, i.e. what to find from.

```
list_to_find = my_dict['ftml']['people']['person']
```

The `list_to_find` is a list of dict (people), like

```
[{"@id": "Terach", '@sex': ...}, {"@id": 'Avraham', ...} ...]
```

Then what you want to do is to search in all the @id, so you can get all the @id by:

```
ids = [person['@id'] for person in list_to_find]
```

And then use `index` to get the index:

```
index = ids.index('Avraham')
```

Comment: I will test this solution to later and update. Thank you !

Comment: @zealseeker this was pretty sweet and far simpler IMO than the other solutions, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most simple thing would probably be:

```py
my_dict = {}  # Defined in the question
x = int(input("Type the chronological person number. (i.e 1 is Avraham): "))

persons = my_dict['ftml']['people']['person']
for i, v in enumerate(persons):
    if v['@id'] == x:
        break

# i now has the most recent index
print(i)
```

Your intention: "For example, if the user sends the program "Avraham" the program will return 1. If the user is looking for Nachor the program will return 0." is implemented by this. However, above would work in in reverse... as the iteration will go from top to bottom in this representation...

`reversed(persons)`... :)

Comment: Thank you, It's working to. Just needed to remove the int() from x=... Since I am get String and not integer. Once removed and typed "Avraham" I got "1" as expected. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

just reverse the dictionary like so:

```
reversed_dict = {}
for i in range(0,len(my_dict['ftml']['people']['person'])):
   reversed_dict[my_dict['ftml']['people']['person'][i]['@id']] = {'index':i}
print(reversed_dict)
print(reversed_dict['Avraham']['index'])
```

this should give you the outout of

{'Terach': {'index': 0}, 'Avraham': {'index': 1}, 'Sara': {'index': 2}, 'Nachor': {'index': 3}}
1